# JQuery UI pseudo selector base widget class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a base widget class simply called "baseWidget" and a bunch of various widgets that extend from this class.  I'm hoping to find a way to select the baseWidget class with a pseudo selector rather than simply having a separate selector for each class.

$(':ssi-AmpMeter') works great, $(':ssi-baseWidget') returns an empty set.

The goal in the long run is to have each widget that extends from baseWidget to run a function that is defined in the baseWidget class.

My hope was something along the lines of:

```
$.widget("ssi.baseWidget", {

    ... Removed to cut down on size ...

    testFunction: function(){
        console.log("yay");
    }

});

$.widget( "ssi.AmpMeter", $.ssi.baseWidget, { .. Removed to cut down size ..    });

// Instantiate an AmpMeter widget and add it to the DOM
$("<li>").AmpMeter(.. Removed for size ..);

.. Later in code ..
$(':ssi-baseWidget').baseWidget("testFunction");
```

However, this doesn't work at all and instead gives me an invalid pseudo selector error in the Chrome console.

Any thoughts on how to go about doing this successfully?